# Problema com timing de animação com SVG

Tags: css, animação, svg

Estou tentando fazer uma animação de SVG usando CSS bem simples, aonde estrelas surgem dentro de si mesmas infinitamente. O único problema é que depois do primeiro loop uma das paths começa a passar por cima das outras, o que não é o objetivo. Tentei olhar e não consigo achar o erro ou solução. Segue ela no Codepen: http://codepen.io/guilhermehff/pen/aWZrbP?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Depois de mais algum tempo fazendo testes, percebi que as camadas em `SVG` funcionam por ordem do `html`, ou seja, uma delas sempre estava por cima das outras, causando o problema original. Para solucionar isto, eu utilizei um `clip-path`para manter o SVG dentro do tamanho e mudei o `animation`para estourar os limites, criando o efeito que queria.